# bash: What is a jobspec

Tags: linux, bash, unix, jobs

While reading documentation [1], the term "jobspec" appears a few times.

What is a jobspec?

[1] https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Job-Control-Builtins.html

Comment: A concept that has nothing to do with programming [and for which questions thus belong on SuperUser], since it's part of functionality that isn't enabled in noninteractive use. :)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Whether this belongs on superuser is an open question. The job control builtins _are_ available to a script (e.g. you can do `wait %1`). An example usage: a script that will video transcode several thousand files. The script runs on an 8 core machine. The script uses job control to manage 8 worker processes, starting a new one when an old one completes. I usually do this sort of thing in perl, but it could be done in bash.

Comment: @CraigEstey, you can only do `wait %1` if `[[ $- = *m* ]]` ("monitor mode"), which is false by default in noninteractive shells (and incompatible with some other useful functionality, such as `shopt -s lastpipe`). Otherwise, you need to wait by PID to collect exit status, which is the usual way for scripts such as the one you suggest above to do so (`start_encoder & encoder_pids+=( $! ); ...; for pid in "${encoder_pids[@]}"; do wait "$pid" || echo "Encoder failed"; done` or such).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I just did a `wait %1` in a script with a `$-` value of `hB` and it worked. In the transcoding example, you'd be doing a loop, watching for changes in the `jobs` output, rather than waiting [as you want to start a new job when _any_ of the pending ones complete, not when all 8 are done]. There may be more usual ways to do it, but it is a valid way.

Comment: I stand corrected on the monitor-mode requirement.

Comment: @CraigEstey, ...but how are you blocking until something exits? If you're just polling in your loop, the conventional approach is `kill -0` targeted at PIDs... but really, I tend to call that kind of situation a job for `xargs -P 8`, or anything else that can wait for a SIGCHLD rather than needing to poll.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy sleep in loop. My actual script outputs progress window for jobs with elapsed + ETA (based on input file position from /proc/pid/fd/...), so it needs to wake periodically (i.e. poll). Also, it monitors a directory for new "job requests", cancellations, higher priority jobs. Easy in perl/python, harder in bash, but will work. So loop would do: check for new jobs, check `jobs` for status change, output progress, retire completed file/job, start worker with next file, sleep. It might have to suspend a lower prior job and start a higher prior one. Also, may run on diff machine, etc

Answer (score 35, accepted):

[The job control section of Greg's Bash Guide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/JobControl#jobspec) describes this as follows:

> A job specification or "jobspec" is a way of referring to the processes that make up a job. A jobspec may be:
>
> - `%n` to refer to job number `n`.
> - `%str` to refer to a job which was started by a command beginning with `str`. It is an error if there is more than one such job.
> - `%?str` to refer to a job which was started by a command containing `str`. It is an error if there is more than one such job.
> - `%%` or `%+` to refer to the current job: the one most recently started in the background, or suspended from the foreground. fg and bg will operate on this job if no jobspec is given.
> - `%-` for the previous job (the job that was `%%` before the current one).

Comment: When you didn't write something yourself, it should be attributed -- not just with a link, but with prose making it clear which content is and is not an original part of your answer.

Comment: @Charles Duffy Got it. I'll edit accordingly. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure I would call the Bash Guide "the documentation" though sometimes I think it should be. =)

Comment: @EtanReisner, heh, my fault -- I didn't look closely at where the link was going and assumed it was a different piece of the manual. :)

Comment: In bash, `%` itself refers to the current job too. By the way, the bash manual is sufficently good but is not somewhat comprehensive, plus little examples.

Comment: Can someone add an example how to set a "jobspec" and find a process by its "jobspec"?